# Ordering Looped Results by Field's Numerical Value

Tags: forloop, loop

I’m looping through some text fields on the form results page and need to order the numerical output from low to high.

**How would I do this using twig?**

```
{% for field in submission %}
  {% submission[field.handle].value %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note: I am using the Freeform Plugin. They have informed me that I would need to create a custom filter but before I do that wanted to see if there was a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an extra plugin but SuperSort would do the job - https://github.com/TopShelfCraft/SuperSort

Edit - couldn't make it work in one go, but this works:

`{% set results = [] %}
{% for field in submission %}
  {% set results = results | merge([{'handle': field.handle, 'value': submission[field.handle].value}]) %}
{% endfor %}
{% set sortedResults = results | supersort('sortAs', '{value}', SORT_NUMERIC) %}`

Not the most elegant, let me know if you find a better solution!

Comment: Thanks, Seb - it isn't that clear how we would use the plugin in this scenario though.

Comment: Would the following be correct?

{% for field in submission | supersort('sortAs', 'submission[field.handle].value', SORT_NUMERIC) %}

Comment: yes though I believe you need to use the twig delimiters, and use object (untested):

`{% set sortedSubmission = submission | supersort('sortAs', '{{ submission[object.handle].value }}', SORT_NUMERIC) %}`

Comment: actually this doesn't work, just edited my answer above with another solution

Comment: Thanks - I get an "Array to string conversion" error when adding this line: {% set sortedResults = results | supersort('sortAs', '{value}', SORT_NUMERIC) %}

Comment: can you paste the whole code excerpt?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99032/discussion-between-dan-lee-and-seb).